# How to convert ISO8601 to Date format in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

**How to convert this (*in ISO8601 format*):** 2014-03-13T09:05:50.240Z

**To this (*in MySQL DATE format*):** 2014-03-13

in php?

Comment: Well, it certainly seems like that grabbing the part of the input that comes before the `T` will give you the result you want. Have you tried doing that, for example with `substr`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHP: How convert an ISO8601 date to a different format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458585/using-php-how-convert-an-iso8601-date-to-a-different-format)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

try this

```
$date = '2014-03-13T09:05:50.240Z';

$fixed = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

The complete date function documentation can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

The PHP function "strtotime" does nothing else then converting your timestring into an unix timestamp.

Hope I could help :)

P.s.:
Just in case strtotime will return 0 try using this:

```
$date = '2014-03-13T09:05:50.240Z';

$fixed = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(substr($date,0,10)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much... it worked awesome! Your last note for using `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(substr($date,0,10)))` if it returned 0 was perfect. That was the one that worked well for me! It did help me a lot! Thank you... :)

Answer (score 18):

Since PHP `5.2.0` you can do it using **OOP** and [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) as well (of course if you prefer OOP):

```
$now = new DateTime("2014-03-13T09:05:50.240Z");
echo $now->format('Y-m-d');    // MySQL datetime format
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to use the inefficient time functions. The most efficient way is to simply extract the first 10 characters:

```
substr($date,0,10)
```

People, that are really coding for year ≥10000, can use:

```
substr($date,0,strpos($date,"T"))
```

Comment: That will break in the year 10000

Comment: A year 10000 solution added ;)

Answer (score 3):

Simply convert  datetime description into a Unix timestamp using with [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and then five format using [Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Try it will surely work for you.

```
$date = '2014-03-13T09:05:50.240Z';

$fixed = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Thx Mitul. That appears to work but if the format is different from my original questions, for example: `Thu Mar 13 2014 17:21:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`, after its converted, the `$fixed` values is outputting it as 1970-01-01. So is it different method for this format?

Comment: Actually @ThatMSG suggestion of using `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(substr($date,0,10)))` worked!. Thank you Mitul for your support!

Comment: @blackops_programmer : it will definitely work whatever format you send.[check your example](http://codepad.org/J33kvRm4).

Answer (score 0):

For those using Carbon (php library), the `parse()` works quite well:

`Carbon::parse($date)`

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Today I have published an [interitty/utils](https://gitlab.com/interitty/utils#createfromiso8601) package that deals with, among other things, the ISO-8601 format and perhaps all permutations of this standard.

I hope it will help you too.

```php
$dateTimeFactory = new Interitty\Utils\DateTimeFactory();
$dateTime = $dateTimeFactory->createFromIso8601('1989-12-17T12:00:00Z');
```