# Display date from database in Angularjs and view the current date for update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, date

I'm updating a form in angularjs, one of the fields is **Date Joined**

I want to display the current value of date joined from the database to the field, but when I use input type `date` the value doesn't display

but when I changed the type to `text`, the value displays.

My question is, how can I display and update the `date_joined` using `type=date`?

EDIT:
Here's the code:

HTML:

```
 <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">
                <b>Date Joined:</b>
            </span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="memUpdate.date_joined" ng-value="memDataViaId.date_joined"></input>
        </label>
```

I'm using SQLite.

here's my query in my JS:

```
var query = "SELECT members.*, branches.name as branch_name, branches.id as branches, branches.name as branch_name, "
    + "groups.name as group_name, groups.id as groups, civil_statuses.name as civil_status_name, "
    + "civil_statuses.id as civil_statuses, religions.id as religions, educations.id as educations, "
    + "mem_join_resigns.date_joined as date_joined, .....
```

Comment: There is little information about the problem. We don't know if you are using `mySQL` - using a date picker? - what back-end? For php you will have to format your date to align the correct mysql dateformat (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376415/how-to-convert-iso8601-to-date-format-in-php)

Comment: please provide your code so we can look into it.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to give the date in following format "yyyy-MM-dd".
- Inject `$filter` service in the controller and then use like this

  ```
  $filter("date")(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  ```

Here, in the syntax `myDate` is the date coming from the database.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) { 
    var myDate = '2010-10-29T00:00:00';
    $scope.date = $filter("date")(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="date" ng-model="date">
    </div>
</body>
```