# Human readable UTC datetime

Tags: php, date, utc

I have date time in this format:

```
2017-04-01T17:35:00.000Z
```

how can I format it with Php and transform it in a nicer look to read?

I tried with:

```
date_format('2017-04-01T17:35:00.000Z',"F j, Y, g:i a");
```

and it returns me a false boolean

Comment: What did that give as output?  An error?  Why wasn't it "successful"?

Comment: It returns me a false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert ISO8601 to Date format in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376415/how-to-convert-iso8601-to-date-format-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**PHP Code demo**](https://eval.in/771382)

```
<?php
$timestamp=  strtotime("2017-04-01T17:35:00.000Z");
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a",$timestamp);
```

**Output:**

```
April 1, 2017, 5:35 pm
```

Comment: My result is April 1, 2017, 7:35 pm. Why it is two hours later than your?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione `17:35:00` is `05:35 PM`