# How to convert date string containing Letters and extra numbers to datetime

Tags: php, string, datetime

I have a date string returned from Go Cardless Api in the format of 
"2017-03-29T09:46:35.937Z" I want to just keep the Y-m-d H:i:s part and to remove the T and remove everything after the seconds. I have been looking around at the php docs and I think DateTime::createFromFormat should be able to do this but I cant find any good examples anywhere

Comment: echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2017-03-29T09:46:35.937Z'));

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309621/human-readable-utc-datetime/43309685#43309685

Answer (score 0):

One option would just be to use the substr(...); function.

$yourdatestring = substr($yourdatestring, 0, 10) . ' ' . substr($yourdatestring, 11, 8);