# Can't format a UTC date in PHP

Tags: php

With a php app, I have a date like this '2019-07-22T04:44:43.843710438Z' and I can't figure out how to convert it to a date like this 7/22/2019 3:11 PM. strtotime just returns false, I tried a few time zones and nothing works. Here is my scratch pad of stuff I've been trying

```
 $timestamp = '2019-07-22T04:44:43.843710438Z';
//$reset = date_default_timezone_get();
//date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
//$stamp = strtotime($timestamp);
//date_default_timezone_set($reset);

$result = date_parse_from_format("j F Y G:i", $timestamp);
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ISO 8601 but it looks like the ending decimal doesn't comply with what PHP expects. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376415/how-to-convert-iso8601-to-date-format-in-php works if the decimal is only 2 places. `G:i` isn't going to have seconds anyway so might as well just trim it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have a much easier time (couldn't resist) working with the DateTime class (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

You're running into issues because the value you have isn't a timestamp so you can't use it like one.

The original time value uses nanosecond precision (9dp) which isn't supported by PHP. In order to use that time string with DateTime, you'll first have to truncate it to microseconds (6dp). It then has a method that will return your value in the desired format (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$time = '2019-07-22T04:44:43.843710438Z';
$time_micro_precision = substr($time, 0, -4) . 'Z'; // drop the last three digits to move from nanoseconds to microseconds.

$datetime = new DateTime($time_micro_precision);
echo $datetime->format('j/n/Y g:i A');
```

Comment: For this, I get 
FATAL ERROR Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2019-07-22T04:44:43.843710438Z) at position 0 (2): The timezone could not be found in the database

Comment: @user204588 I hadn't looked too closely at the date in question. Where are you getting that from? It appears to be to 9dp.

Comment: It's from an external API

Comment: The time you have is down to nanosecond precision which to my knowledge PHP doesn't support. How you deal with this is going to depend on what you want to do with that time. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: You should be able to use 8dp with DateTime. 8dp implies 100th of a microsecond which is more than 1 nanosecond. 8dp works with strtotime, which also supports microsecond precision

Comment: @NadirLatif Accepts and supports are two different things. You may be able to pass in a value to 8dp but it doesn't mean that it's going to recognise and work with that degree of precision. Take a look at `u` under possible date formats: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Using **strtotime** works if you restrict the timestamp to 2 decimal places. Try the following:

```
$time      = "2019-07-22T04:44:43.843710438Z";
$temp_str = rtrim($time, "Z");
$temp_arr = explode(":", $temp_str);
$temp_str = number_format($temp_arr[count($temp_arr)-1], 8);
$time     = $temp_arr[0] . ":" . $temp_arr[1] . ":" . $temp_str . "Z";

$timestamp = strtotime($time);
echo date("m/d/Y H:i a", $timestamp);
```

Comment: as you can see in the answer above yours, using `DateTime` class is best. No need to use string manipulations like explode

Comment: Looks like even with DateTime, I have to remove decimal

Comment: DateTime and strtime both support microsecond precision. So 8 decimal places are supported by both. I have updated the answer so it allows 8 decimal places for the time. If you dont need the extra precision, you can remove the decimal places from the time stamp